# NoClassDefFoundError for a class due to the interrelative dependencies in karaf

Tags: grpc, classnotfoundexception, noclassdeffounderror, apache-karaf, opendaylight

Consider the below scenario where i am getting an unexpected error and unable to fix it.

In Opendaylight architype project, I just used a class(Say test.class from **io-example** dependency) when I just declared only one dependency (i.e io-example) in the pom.xml, there is no error.

But if i add one more dependency (**io-example-api**) in the pom.xml, I am getting java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/example/test.class
at org.opendaylight.gnmi.impl.base.OpenconfigInter
..................................................
..................................................
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: io.example.Test cannot be found by org.opendaylight

I found that io.example-api has the io-example as the dependency.. Summarize the issue, If i have the io-example alone in the pom.xml, there is no issue. If I have both io-example and io-example-api in the pom.xml, I am getting the NoclassDef error.

Even I have tried the exclusion option in the dependency section, Nothing works.

Thanks in advance...

Edited:

classname : io.grpc.Context

Dependencies :

```
<dependency>
           <groupId>io.grpc</groupId>
            <artifactId>grpc-context</artifactId>
            <version>1.38.0</version>
       </dependency>

       <dependency>
             <groupId>io.grpc</groupId>
             <artifactId>grpc-api</artifactId>
             <version>1.38.0</version>
       </dependency>
```

In karaf container, I ran the "package:exports" commands and the results are,

```
opendaylight-user@root>package:exports -p io.grpc
 
        io.grpc   0.0.0  354 wrap_file__home_verizon_gnmi_gnmi_karaf_target_assembly_system_io_grpc_grpc-api_1.38.0_grpc-api-1.38.0.jar

    io.grpc   0.0.0  355 wrap_file__home_verizon_gnmi_gnmi_karaf_target_assembly_system_io_grpc_grpc-context_1.38.0_grpc-context-1.38.0.ja



opendaylight-user@root>package:exports -d
       io.grpc  0.0.0  354 355

You can see that, io.grpc package exported by two bundles (354 and
```

355)..

Answer (score 0):

A common cause for `ClassNotFoundException` in OSGi and Karaf is that multiple bundles export the same package with the same version. This causes only one of them be imported which may or may not contain your Test class.

Check which packages export io.example with package:exports command:

```sh
packages:exports -p io.example
```

I am guessing that adding the dependency causes your bundle to import the package `io.example` from `io-example-api` instead of `io-example`.

Solution for this would be to make sure only one bundle exports `io.example` package.

[Edit] I am unfamiliar with grpc but there seems to be [issue on github](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/issues/2727) about this and some workarounds that you could look in to.

You could also try creating a bundle that embeds these problematic dependencies and exports the packages for other bundles to use.

1. Create a new bundle project using archetype `karaf-bundle-archetype`
2. Add `grpc-context` and `grpc-api` dependencies
3. Configure maven-bundle-plugin to emped the grpc dependencies and export io.grpc package along with its sub packages.

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${maven-bundle-plugin.version}</version>
    <extensions>true</extensions>
    <configuration>
        <instructions>
            <Bundle-SymbolicName>
                ${project.groupId}.${project.artifactId}
            </Bundle-SymbolicName>
            <Bundle-Version>${project.version}</Bundle-Version>
            <Bundle-Activator>com.example.Activator</Bundle-Activator>
            <Import-Package>
                *;resolution:=optional
            </Import-Package>
            <Export-Package>
                io.grpc*;-split-package:=merge-first
            </Export-Package>
            <Emped-Dependency>
                grpc-context;scope=compile|runtime;inline=true,
                grpc-api;scope=compile|runtime;inline=true
            </Emped-Dependency>
        </instructions>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Managed to install the bundle successfully to Karaf 4.2.11 and "use" the exported `io.grpc.Context` class in the bundle and in another bundle.

Simply called this from the Activator of two bundles

```java
Context grpcContext = Context.current();
System.out.println(grpcContext.getClass().getName());
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.. You're right.. The same package exported by both bundles.

Comment: I have updated the details in the questions more.. please look  into it and provide any suggestions. @Pasi Österman

Comment: Found Github issue related to this and tested out one way one could create a bundle to hold these problematic dependencies as Emped-dependencies and export the packages for other bundles to use in karaf. But only did some light testing on it as I am unfamiliar with grpc so you might still encounter some issues with it but hopefully it'll help you forward. Updated the answer.